# get current time / date from php in format similar to 2012-04-24T00:00:00Z

Tags: php, date

How can I get php to provide me a string I can compare with the datestring format 2012-04-24T00:00:00Z?

I'm seeing lots of ways to get this from SQL, but I'm getting these dates from a webservice and am trying to filter lots of them with as little manipulation as possible.  My hope is to get the current date / time from php in the SQL format and just try a string based comparison.

EDIT:  I had erroneously thought this was SQL format, which probably explains some of the difficulties I had trying to find an answer to this question.  I'm not sure what standard it is, but I was told this is a popular convention.

Comment: Note: `2012-04-24T00:00:00Z` is NOT SQL format...

Comment: Yikes, apologies... outside my area, I'll update my question. Any idea which format this is?

Comment: To insert `datetime` or `timestamp` values in MySQL, use the format 'Y-m-d H:i:s' e.g. '2014-06-04 14:44:00'

Comment: Getting these from a webservice, more concerned with what standard I'm dealing with as I will not be interacting with a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `date()` with the proper formatting flags:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z");
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/HhX0ze)

Comment: Seems so obvious, had a lot of trouble finding this, thanks!  works fine.